# Add DB timestamp to SQL Loader CSV import

Tags: oracle, excel, csv, timestamp, sql-loader

I have a client who's CSV file does not contain any dates.  They would like a timestamp to indicate as to when each row is loaded into their Oracle 11g database.  The CSV file is being supplied by a vendor so I cannot modify the file.  I have tried adding a default column value and an "after insert" trigger but with no luck. (Performance is not an issue as this is an off- hours process).

The control files looks like this:

```
options (skip=1, direct=true, rows=10000)
load data
 infile data.dat
badfile sqldatatxtdata.bad
replace
     into table LAM.CSV_DATA_TXT
fields terminated by ','
trailing nullcols
(ASSET, ASSET_CLASS, MATURITY, PRICE)
```

The table looks like such:

```
create table LAM.CSV_DATA_TXT  (
ASSET   VARCHAR2(20),
ASSET_CLASS   VARCHAR2(50),
MATURITY  varchar2(50),
PRICE  NUMBER(12,8),
DATE_TIMESTAMP DATE default(SYSTIMESTAMP)
```

Any other ideas?  Thanks.

Comment: "but with no luck. "  Please expand on what you mean by this.  Do you get an error?  Does the load fail?  Or is the column left blank?  The more details you give us, the more likely we can help you.

Answer (score 0):

Adding a TIMESTAMP column with a default value of SYSTIMESTAMP ought to worK:

```
SQL> create table t23
  2  ( id number not null
  3      , ts timestamp default systimestamp not null)
  4  /

Table created.

SQL> insert into t23 (id) values (9999)
  2  /

1 row created.

SQL> select * from t23
  2  /

        ID  TS
----------  ------------------------- 
      9999  25-APR-11 15.21.01.495000


SQL>
```

So you'll need to explain in greater detail why it doesn't work in your case.

---

I note that in your example you have created the column as a DATE datatype.  This will mean it will truncate the defaulted SYSTIMESTAMP to the nearest second.  If you want timestamp values you need to use the TIMESTAMP datatype.

Comment: I actually figured it out.  It was a commit issue.  When using SQL Loader to load the csv file into the database, you need to set direct=false. This will allow you to use a column default value in the database.  If it's set to true-- it will not populate.